# winform: how to rearrange the menu?

Tags: winforms, menu

based on .designer.cs, i infer that the menu's arrangement is based on the order you add them on menuStrip's AddRange method:

```
this.menuStrip.Items.AddRange(new System.Windows.Forms.ToolStripItem[] {
            this.windowsMenu,
            this.helpMenu});
```

is there a way i can change the order of menu? i put dynamically generated menu in my code, they always appear after the helpMenu, is there a way i can re-order the menu?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you are adding items to the menuStrip, use the Insert method, specifying the index that you want the menu inserted at.

For example, to add a menu item in the first position:

```
menuStrip.Items.Insert(0, new ToolStripMenuItem { Text = "Sample" });
```